# getting the type of parameters passed in a variable arguments list

Tags: c++, opencv, variadic-functions

I have written a function with variable argument list

```
void cvShowMatImages( char* title, int nArgs, ...)  // Mat Images
```

where the argument to pass are openCV images.
I have actually 2 different functions for the 2 image formats IplImage and Mat, the above mentioned and a second one

```
void cvShowIplImages( char* title, int nArgs, ...)  // Ipl Images
```

But I cannot mix images of the 2 types.
I could resolve my issue if I would be able to determine the type of argument passed, but I do not know how to do.
This is how I read the argument:

```
// Get the images passed as arguments
va_list args;
// Initialize the variable argument list
va_start( args, nArgs );
// Loop on each image
for ( int num = 0; num < nArgs; num++ )
{
   // Get the image to be copied from the argument list
   srcImg = va_arg( args, Mat );
   ...
```

and for IplImage:

```
srcImg = va_arg( args, IplImage* );
```

In both case srcImg is declared as

```
Mat srcImg
```

since there is an overloaded operator= for IplImage.
Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use-case for variadic templates (well, in the end every use of good (bad?) old ellipses is a perfect use-case for them).

Comment: Variable arguments aren't typesafe.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Why did you remove the C tag?

Comment: @alk Because I would wonder how you would make sense out of things like `cv::Mat` and `operator=` in C code. Both are completely different languages (sad truth: there is no *"C/C++"*) and you have to decide for one, which the OP did when using `cv::Mat`.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Ups ... I obviously missed the OP's last line.

Answer (score 1):

Using `variadic templates` in this manner is a possible solution:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args> void func(double t, Args... args) ;
template<typename... Args> void func(int t, Args... args) ;

void func(int t) 
{
    std::cout << "int: "<< t << std::endl ;
}

void func(double t) 
{
    std::cout << "double: "<< t << std::endl ;
}

template<typename... Args>
void func(double t, Args... args) 
{
    func(t) ;
    func(args...) ;
}

template<typename... Args>
void func(int t, Args... args) 
{
    func(t) ;
    func(args...) ;
}


int main()
{
    int x1 = 1, x2 = 5 ;
    double d1 = 2.5 , d2 = 3.5;

    func( x1 , d1, x2 ) ;
    func( x1 , d1, d2 ) ;
}
```

It is not very elegant but it may help solve your problem. Another method would be to use two `std::initializer_list` one for each type, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

void func2( std::initializer_list<int> listInt, std::initializer_list<double> listDouble )
{
    for( auto elem : listInt )
    {
        std::cout << "Int: " << elem << std::endl ;
    }

    for( auto elem : listDouble )
    {
        std::cout << "double: " << elem << std::endl ;
    }
}

int main()
{
    func2( {10, 20, 30, 40 }, {2.5, 2.5 }) ;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather consider passing tuple or array or a vector.

As `std::array` is template with N, it is possible to make your function a template with N too, and implement in a generic way. Variadic template is also viable if your complier is good for it.

The ... is something we try to get rid of. It's undefined behavior to pass anything non-POD, and no type check is possible. What makes it way too prone to errors. For your case it is not very helpful either.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I thank you all for your contribution!

I have not a C++11 compliant compiler, so some of your proposals won´t be working.

Anyway, I have found a rather simple solution - which I never thought to be working! - which is just casting the argument containing an IplImage to Mat!

example:

```
cvShowMatImages( "all my Ipl and Mat images", 2, myMatImage, (Mat)myIplImage );
```